# How to clear away the CloseButton on ActionMode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

When It is in ActionMode, there is a closeButton on topleft of the screen,when I use setCustomView() to define my own layout, it will appear on the right of the CloseButton.

and in Theme/Style xml file I could just change the style of this button ,cannot clear it.

so, Is there someway to clear away this CloseButton? thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `cannot clear it` are you trying to hide the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this on your main theme:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionModeCloseButton</item>
```

Then define:

```
<style name="ActionModeCloseButton" parent="android:style/Widget.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You got it. Don't forget to tick the checkmark if the answer solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [dokkaebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931277/dokkaebi), it works. But i perfer to use "invisible":

```
<style name="NoCloseButtonActionModeStyle">
   <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
</style>
```

So the custom view position in ActionMode will not indent to parent left.